# C# Compare one List string with substring of other list string

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists

```
List<string> ingoreEducationKeywords= new List<string>(){"Uni", "School", "College",}; 
List<string> userEducation= new List<string>(){"MCS", "BCS", "School of Arts","College of Medicine"};
```

Now I want to get a list which has no substring from the ignore list.

require list {"MCS", "BCS"}

Comment: Use an Left Outer Join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @jdweng: I see no need a join here...

Comment: `userEducation.Where(e => ignoreEducationKeywords.All(i => !e.Contains(i)))`

Comment: This code example smells like a homework

Comment: no, this is a task to parse resume from Linkedin PDF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a relatively straightforward query that can be constructed with `Any` or `All`, depending on your preferences:

```
var res = userEducation
    .Where(s => !ingoreEducationKeywords.Any(ignored => s.Contains(ignored)))
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var res = userEducation
    .Where(s => ingoreEducationKeywords.All(ignored => !s.Contains(ignored)))
    .ToList();
```

If the lists are very large, you could improve performance by using regex to match all words simultaneously:

```
var regex = new Regex(
    string.Join("|", ingoreEducationKeywords.Select(Regex.Escape))
);
var res = userEducation.Where(s => !regex.IsMatch(s)).ToList();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Nxy8j0)

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of phrasing what you want in a way that leads to a natural translation into LINQ:

- You want items from `userEducation` (that suggests you'll start with `userEducation`)
- Where *none* of `ignoreEducationKeywords` are substrings.

  - "None" is equivalent to "not any"
  - To check for substrings you can use `Contains`

That leads to:

```
var query = userEducation
   .Where(candidate => !ignoredKeyWords.Any(ignore => candidate.Contains(ignore)));
```

The same thought process can help in many other queries.

Another option would be to create your own `None` extension method, assuming you're using LINQ to Objects:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool None(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        => !source.Any(predicate);
}
```

Then you could rewrite the query without the negation:

```
var query = userEducation
   .Where(candidate => ignoredKeyWords.None(ignore => candidate.Contains(ignore)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Where`, `Any` and `Contains`:

```
var list = userEducation.Where(ed => !ingoreEducationKeywords.Any(ik => ed.Contains(ik)));
```

It searches all occurences in `userEducation` where the education does not have any match in `ingoreEducationKeywords`.

Comment: Like Jon you're missing a trailing `)`

Comment: Like Jon I can't count @juharr :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> ingoreEducationKeywords = new List<string>() { "Uni", "School", "College", };
List<string> userEducation = new List<string>() { "MCS", "BCS", "School of Arts", "College of Medicine" };

var result = userEducation.Where(r => !ingoreEducationKeywords.Any(t => r.Contains(t))).ToList();
```